# Count number of sequential records based on condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands, postgresql-9.6

I have a table that has number of rows that originally sorted by timestamp:

```
+----+------------+-----+
| id | date       | foo |
+----+------------+-----+
| 1  | 2017-12-28 | abc |
+----+------------+-----+
| 1  | 2017-12-27 | abc |
+----+------------+-----+
| 2  | 2017-12-27 | xyz |
+----+------------+-----+
| 2  | 2017-12-26 | xyz |
+----+------------+-----+
| 2  | 2017-12-25 | abc |
+----+------------+-----+
| 1  | 2017-12-25 | abc |
+----+------------+-----+
| 2  | 2017-12-25 | abc |
+----+------------+-----+
```

And I want to get number of *sequential* records with same `foo` for different `id` like that:

```
+----+-----+-------+
| id | foo | count |
+----+-----+-------+
| 1  | abc | 2     |
+----+-----+-------+
| 2  | xyz | 2     |
+----+-----+-------+
| 2  | abc | 1     |
+----+-----+-------+
| 1  | abc | 1     |
+----+-----+-------+
| 2  | abc | 1     |
+----+-----+-------+
```

So, [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/35078/2/0) is sqlfiddle with built schema.

Window functions look like a key for such kind of problems but it didn't worked out well in the way I used.

I'll be glad to get any help or at least some hints that can be useful.
There is some questions on MySQL related to this but they aren't very helpful though.

Comment: Not an answer, but what is being used to order the last three records of the input data, where the date is `2017-12-25` for all three?  This is a gaps and islands problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this is just for readability. Records are sorted in descending order by timestamp and I used longer datetime string in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thanks a lot for your sqlfiddle.

Use the standard approach(Tabibitosan) for gaps and islands problem using `row_number()`

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/35078/33)

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table bar (
  id   bigint not null,
  date timestamp without time zone,
  foo  text
);

insert into bar (id, date, foo) values
  (1, '2017-12-28 17:54:02', 'abc'),
  (1, '2017-12-28 17:53:30', 'abc'),
  (2, '2017-12-28 17:50:13', 'xyz'),
  (2, '2017-12-28 17:44:35', 'xyz'),
  (2, '2017-12-28 17:30:00', 'abc'),
  (1, '2017-12-28 17:25:15', 'abc'),
  (2, '2017-12-28 17:21:20', 'abc');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT MAX (id) AS id,
         foo,
         COUNT (*) AS "count"
    FROM (SELECT b.*,
                   ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY date DESC)
                 - ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC)
                    seq
            FROM bar b) t
GROUP BY foo, seq, id
ORDER BY MAX(DATE) DESC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/35078/33/0)**:

```
| id | foo | count |
|----|-----|-------|
|  1 | abc |     2 |
|  2 | xyz |     2 |
|  2 | abc |     1 |
|  1 | abc |     1 |
|  2 | abc |     1 |
```

Comment: That's handy. Also thanks for the reference to gaps and islands problem. I've add as tag so maybe it will be helpful to someone else.

Comment: It behaves strange sometimes. e.g. with [this dataset](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7aa36/1). It counts (3, 5), (3, 1) and not (3, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2).

Comment: OK, asked and just now solved by `partition by id, foo`.